# How to find the best Queue in a non normal distribution

Tags: statistics, queueing-theory

I've been thinking about this problem for a little bit but did not find a satisfactory answer, maybe you guys can help me!

I have N queues processing data all day, and I have to find the best or a few better for some period of time to gain efficiency. But the processing time response is not normal, in fact here is an example:
[Processing time distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s6Wv.jpg)

What metrics or tests I can monitor to help me decide which one is the fastest?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you wish to find optimal processing speeds so as to minimise the queueing times while simultaneously keeping $N$ reasonably small?

Comment: I can use as many Queues as I want, I just want to find the best performing queues, maybe rank them.